# Error when try to run a website in Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I have very basic knowledge of coding, I took a copy of our company's website to practice making changes to it.

But when I try to run it I get this error

> Warning: require_once(/var/www/html/classes/database_class_pdo.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\HJ\top.php on line 10
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/var/www/html/classes/database_class_pdo.php'
>   (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\HJ\top.php on
>   line 10

Please, can someone tell me the issue here?
Thank you.

Comment: Your paths are defined absolutely, you need to change the directory structure on your system or change the code so it calls relative,

Comment: "_No such file or directory_" Warning message is quite clear, a PHP script tries to include a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, you seem to be working on a Windows machine, whereas your company's website runs on a Linux machine, you'll likely have to replace `/var/www/html/` in that project to fit your Windows paths. Hard to say without any code

Comment: In the config.php file, the path is defined as `code`define('DOC_ROOT','/var/www/html/'); 
how does it work in Xampp?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your php file is trying to open a file named `/var/www/html/classes/database_class_pdo.php` but cannot find it. Try to see if the path is correct or if the file exists.